# Happiness 'from' vs 'of' vs 'to'?

Tags: grammaticality, difference, prepositions

> [**utilitarianism =**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/utilitarianism) the belief that the right course of action is the one that will produce the greatest happiness **of** the greatest number of people

I would've first chosen happiness + **from** or **to**, so would someone please explain the preposition **of** here? Could others be used? If so, which? What are the similarities and differences?

2. What's this phenomenon called? Does it occur to other words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To produce the greatest happiness **of** the greatest number of people.

The sentence implies the happiness will belong to the people, thus, they will be happy.

> To produce the greatest happiness **from** the greatest number of people.

The sentence implies the happines will be produced *using* people. Such process could make them rather unhappy if overdone. Who is to become happy is not mentioned here, it could be a single person or multiple persons. Maybe the happiness is to be accumulated and returned to the people from whom it was produced, at a later date.

> To produce the greatest happiness **to** the greatest number of people.

This looks ungrammatical to me. We can "produce something to someone", but this is usually said in formal contexts, such as "to produce papers, documents, drafts, estimates..", and the recipient is usually a government, a regulatory body, the police etc.

**Of** is a [possessive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive) preposition. I quote from Wikipedia:

> *the child's bag* might also be expressed as *the bag **of** the child*
>
> *our cats' mother* might be expressed as *the mother **of** our cats*

Hence,

> The people's happiness -> The happiness **of** the people.

When you choose the prepositions **from** or **to**, they start to work with the verb *produce*, resulting in the combinations *produce something from* and *produce something to*.

> I **produced** my documents **to** the court.
>
> We **produce** cottage cheese **from** milk.

The proposition **of**, on the other hand, does not combine with the verb *produce*. It combines with the noun word *happiness*.

This is not always so: **of** could combine with, or **depend upon**, other verbs. Different prepositions have different *[dependency patterns](http://www.lps.canterbury.ac.nz/lsc/documents/handouts/DPP.pdf)*:

> I **cured** him **of** his tooth-ache.

A [poetic example](http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/%7Ecrshalizi/Poetry/Millay/Upon_this_age.html) of **of** being dependent upon a verb:

> Wisdom enough to **leech** us **of** our ill
>  Is daily spun; but there exists no loom
>  To weave it into fabric; undefiled
>  Proceeds pure Science, and has her say; but still
>  Upon this world from the collective womb
>  Is spewed all day the red triumphant child.

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your continual care. Please maintain your superlative contributions and beneficence, which I cherish.