# Cast about + indirect object pronoun?

Tags: meaning

I consulted http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast%20about and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cast-about-or-around-or-round?q=cast+about but still don't understand why there's an indirect object pronoun after **cast about**? Can **her** be omitted?

Source: Joanna Trollope, *Britannia’s Daughters*, The Cresset Library, 1988

> Miss Rye ran a highly
>   successful law-copying office for women clerks in Lincoln’s Inn Fields, and because
>   she was besieged by the demands of educated women for work, she had **cast
>   about her** for an alternative and suitable occupation and had come up with the idea
>   of emigration. There was a rising demand in Australia, New Zealand and Natal for
>   superior servants and for governesses and Miss Rye felt that the women who
>   begged her for employment would be ideally suited...

**Afterword:**  I thought to mention that [answerer CopperKettle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/34927/8712) linked to a PDF on dependent prepositions patterns, which doesn't contain **cast about**, but am I right that the same phenomenon applies here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There, **her** is a reflexive pronoun.

To "cast about...for {something}" means to look around for something haphazardly, not with a plan of action.

To "cast about {oneself} for {something} " means to look for something haphazardly, without a plan of action, *in one's immediate vicinity*.

In this passage, literal "vicinity" (e.g. in the grass at one's feet, or in one's room) is not what is meant; rather it means "local situation or circumstances".

So it is a weakly metaphorical use of the idea of an unmethodical search for something in one's vicinity.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please be able to cite a dictionary that states the second meaning with the reflexive pronoun? I haven't found one yet.

Comment: I doubt one would find it as a separate entry under the verb because it's not really a separate meaning. Compare *She looked about for something sharp to cut the twine. She looked about her for something sharp to cut the twine.* The first might mean she went all around the suite of offices looking for a pair of scissors or a utility knife. The second might mean she confined her search to the office in which she found herself.

Comment: Thank you again. Would you please see my Afterword in my updated OP? Am I right about that?

Comment: Is your question in respect to the use of the preposition *for* in the verb phrase `cast about (her) for ... {something}`?  Or are you asking about `about`? Or something else? I don't follow.

Comment: My afterword just asks about a reference or source or name of the phenomenons involved in `cast about (her) for ... {something}. Does that help? I interpret this as a case of 'prepositions after a transitive verb', but is there a pithier way to describe this?

Comment: What could be pithier than "prepositions after a transitive verb"?

Comment: Thanks. Well, I fear that "prepositions after a transitive verb"don't suffice, because here, there are two indirect objects `her, something` and two prepositions? So this is a more involved case?

Comment: "Cast about" is not an transitive verb.

Comment: And I've already told you that "her" is a reflexive.